# Where can I find a list of medical conditions and their incidence rates?

Tags: human-physiology, statistics

Where can I find a list of diseases and their incidence rates? I'm giving a presentation on Long QT Syndrome, which affects 1 in 2000 people, or 50 per 100,000. I'm trying to find other, more well-known diseases with a similar incidence to give my audience a frame of reference.

(Note: This is not a duplicate of [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-diseases-and-their-incidence) question. That question is asking about very rare diseases, and the answers to that question reflect that)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The question would be a better fit on [Health.SE](http://health.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The WHO probably have this kind of data. Consider [this document](http://www.who.int/healthinfo/global_burden_disease/GBD_report_2004update_part3.pdf) for example.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize there was a Health.SE, I'll ask there if I can't find it from the WHO